# rails 3 render json and include profile from array

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3

All Users have one profile.

Currently have:

```
render :json => @user, :include => [:friends, :requested_friends]
```

Would like to include the profile for friends and requested friends.

I know for a single include I can user this

```
render :json => @user, :include => {:requested_friends => {:include => :profile}}
```

But need something like:

```
render :json => @user, :include => {[:friends, :requested_friends] => {:include => :profile}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
render :json    => @user,
       :include => {
           :requested_friends => { :include => :profile },
           :friends           => { :include => :profile }
       }
```