# Rails find method - select columns from ":include" table parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

The below find method returns all records but doesn't include venues table columns. Is there a way I can modify the below to include columns from venues? I tried `:select => 'venues.id'`, and `:select => 'venues.*'`, to no avail. Perhaps this is a limitation with the rails find method. Can the query be rewritten as perhaps "Item.where" to include all columns?

```
@vehicles = Vehicle.find(:all, 
      :select => '*',
      :joins => [:vehicle_status, :category, :user],
      :include => [:venue],
      :conditions => ["vehicles.client_id = ? ", current_user.client_id]
      )
```

I'm using rails 3.2.11.

Also, my when I use `:select => 'vehicles.*, venues.*'` and get the follow query on the console where it shows venues fields being selected, but they do not appear in the returned json:

```
    SELECT "vehicles"."id" AS t0_r0, ... "vehicles"."created_at" AS t0_r33, 
"vehicles"."updated_at" AS t0_r34, "venues"."id" AS t1_r0, "venues"."client_id" AS t1_r1, 
"venues"."venue_name" AS t1_r2, "venues"."created_at" AS t1_r3, "venues"."updated_at" AS t1_r4 
FROM "vehicles" INNER JOIN "vehicle_statuses" ON "vehicle_statuses"."vehicle_status_code" = 
"vehicles"."status_code" INNER JOIN "categories" ON "categories"."id" = 
"vehicles"."category_id" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "vehicles"."created_at_user_id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "venues" ON "venues"."id" = "vehicles"."venue_id" WHERE (vehicles.client_id = 
500 )
```

However, if I use `:select => '*'`, the console shows two queries: one for the vehicles table, the other for venue: Venue Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "venues".* FROM "venues" WHERE "venues"."id" IN (5000)

Comment: see here for latter issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715201/weird-left-outer-join-on-includes-eager-loading-of-rails-3?rq=1

Comment: ok, found explanation for my latter concern with the sql query. see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199235/activerecord-query-changing-when-a-dot-period-is-in-condition-value. I still can't figure out how to get venue columns in the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try

```
format.json { render json: @vehicles, :include => :venue }
```

You could also do a join

```
@vehicles = Vehicle.where(client_id: current_user.client_id).joins(:category, :vehicle_status).includes(:venue)
```

venue or venues depending on `has_many` or `has_one`. For further information lookup stuff here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: Didn't work. Also, what about joins to the other table? I tried that too (.joins(:vehicle_status, :category, :user))

Comment: I'm not getting an error - the columns in the venues table isn't returning in the json. I came across a strange behavior when using selecting 'vehicles.*, venues.*' vs selecting '*'. I will update my original post. –

Comment: Have you done something like this `render :json => @vehicles.to_json(:include => :venues)` to render? Here is a link to an accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756914/rails-3-render-json-and-include-profile-from-array

Comment: Amazing!! it worked (ie, `format.json { render json: @vehicles, :include => :venue }` or `render :json => @vehicles.to_json(:include => :venue)`. I don't get it - I am the ONLY one ever needing to do this??? There is NO documentation on this scenario. This would make a good Blog article. Can you update your original response so I can mark it as the answer?

Comment: By the way, this approach makes it a nightmare for data binding at the UI level. For instance, on the UI I bind to email in users simply as "email", now for venue fiels, I have to bind as "venue.venue_name". What a mess.

Comment: `@vehicles = Vehicle.where(client_id: current_user.client_id).joins(:category, :vehicle_status).includes(:venue)` also works. Please update to include `.joins(:category, :vehicle_status)`

Comment: @user1322092 I have made the edits. Go ahead and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

With input from shishirmk, especially on the JSON response, here's the answer:

```
   #where version
   @vehicles = Vehicle.where("vehicles.client_id = ?", current_user.client_id )
   .joins(:category, :vehicle_status, :user)
   .includes(:venue)
   .select("vehicles.id, vehicles.description, categories.category_description, venues.venue_name, users.email")

------ 
   #find version
   @vehicles = Vehicle.find(:all, 
      :select => 'vehicles.id, vehicles.description, categories.category_description, venues.venue_name, users.email',
      :joins => [:vehicle_status, :category, :user],
      :include => [:venue],
      :conditions => ["vehicles.client_id = ?", current_user.client_id])

-----
   format.json { render json: @vehicles, :include => [:venue, :category, :vehicle_status, :user ] }
```

Key lessons:

1) if you include specific columns in your select, child/parent tables won't be JSON root wrapped, and you can simply refer to fields as "venue_name" as opposed "venues.venues_name". So I STRONGLY recommend using SELECT and specifying columns when joining multiple tables with WHERE or FIND. You want to do this since multiple tables will likely have an "id" column.

2) you must be explicit with what your JSON returns (thanks @shishirmk). See my example for returning multiple tables/models.

3) Rails needs better documentation on these types of queries, especially since the framework frowns against using database views :-)