# Rails includes with eager loading => nested models not in to_json version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a class TwitterUser that has many TwitterLists

```
class TwitterUser < ActiveRecord::Base    
    has_many :twitter_lists, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

When I do:

```
user = TwitterUser.includes(:twitter_lists).find(12615489)
```

then:

```
lists = user.twitter_lists
```

it eagerly loads the twitter lists for that user in the first "find", so it doesn't run a query when I do user.twitter_lists (**this is expected**).

However when I try to convert the user to JSON like:
user.to_json

I don't see the nested association "twitter_lists" anywhere in the JSON. Even though I used eager loading. Why is this? And how can I make it appear in the JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include the association in the output of `to_json` you need to pass `:include => :twitter_lists` to `to_json`

There is no connection between the associations that are  eager loaded and the associations that are included in the output of `to_json` - the two are completely independant.

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer 
May be this is what you need

[Rails find method - select columns from ":include" table parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16095252/rails-find-method-select-columns-from-include-table-parameter/16095694#16095694)

includes is just for eager loading. Which means it is cached somewhere but not actually returned